# Any ASP.Net Nuget packages for Trello style URLs?

Tags: asp.net, nuget

Are there Nuget packages that let me generate URLs for my web-app like the way Trello does?

eg. https://trello.com/b/5SMO0Rgh/this-is-my-board

Trello also manages URL redirects after renaming an object so you can paste a link from before the rename and be redirected to the new one. Are there Nuget packages that offer this?

Comment: Or, you could have a go at doing it by yourself? :) Also, is this WebForms, MVC?

Comment: Web API. I can, but I'm hoping it's common enough that someone has done it.

Comment: The task sounds fairly straightforward, you need a route/controller/action adhering to Trello's structure, and some redirect logic when the board name has changed.